# SQL Select unique combinations of rows for other column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m trying to do an analysis of the different combinations of taxes per invoice to identify how many scenarios exist. 
In the tax table, column 1 is invoiceNo, column 2 is taxType. These form the composite key. There can be 1 or more taxType per invoiceNo. Example of data:

https://i.imgur.com/bcQc7vY_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium (Sorry but i’m new so can’t add picture).

I want to be able to report on unique taxType for any invoiceNo. Ie, 1 A is unique comb 1, 2 AB is unique comb 2, 3 A is disregarded as already returned for 1, and 4 BC is unique comb 3.

Not sure if this makes sense! Finding it hard to articulate what I’m after!

Expected output would be:

```
A
AB
BC
```

Comment: Tag appropriate database name. Also add readable sample data with your expected output.

Comment: Hi, I’ve tried to add these things, hopefully that helps a bit. Thank you!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? SQL Server, Postgresql, MySQL, Oracle..? Set the appropriate tag.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had that with the sql tag. It’s Sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with the table you have given and would work with those combinations of Tax types even if they repeat but if there are more tax codes, or there is an AC combination, or if some of the given combinations are omitted then it might get little different! You could develop this to suit the conditions, or you could give some more info: Do invoices have three codes (ABC)? do invoices have just B or just C codes? I notice that the BC invoice etc

```
WITH CTE (RN,InvoiceNo,TT1,TT2) 
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.InvoiceNo),a.InvoiceNo,a.TaxType,b.TaxType 
FROM UniqueCombo a INNER JOIN UniqueCombo b ON a.InvoiceNo=b.InvoiceNo
)
,
CTE2 (RN,InvoiceNo,TT1,TT2) 
AS
(
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN IN
(
SELECT MAX(RN) FROM CTE WHERE TT1=TT2 GROUP BY InvoiceNo HAVING COUNT(InvoiceNo)=1
)
)
SELECT TT1 FROM CTE2 WHERE RN IN
(
SELECT MAX(RN) FROM CTE WHERE TT1=TT2 GROUP BY TT1,TT2 HAVING COUNT(InvoiceNo)>1
)
UNION
SELECT TT1+''+TT2 FROM CTE WHERE RN IN
(
SELECT MAX(RN)-1 FROM CTE WHERE TT1<>TT2 GROUP BY InvoiceNo
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The original version of this question was tagged MySQL, so this answers the question.

If I understand correctly, you can use `group_concat()`:

```
select distinct group_concat(taxtype order by taxtype)
from t
group by invoiceno;
```

Comment: @PeterSmith . . . When I answered the question, the only tag was MySQL.

Comment: Understood, I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try STRING_AGG. Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TaxTypeString
FROM
(
SELECT InvoiceNo, STRING_AGG(TaxType, '') AS TaxTypeString
FROM t
GROUP BY InvoiceNo
) x
ORDER BY TaxTypeString
```

The nested query, called x, should give you one row per invoice number, in the format you want. Then you have to select the distinct tax types from there.

Comment: If user is new to sql probably might help to also show "group by TaxTypeString " which would then let them add the count of invoices (and then they could derive how to add sum of an invoice amount column or add other aggregate functions)